# What is the equivalent of Metamask ethereum.eth.sign in web3.js?

Tags: web3js, metamask

Run the html code, it connect to Metamask then sign a hash message. I try several different ways to sign the message, I want to find out the same method in web3.js that can generate the same output as `new Web3(window.ethereum).eth.sign` does.

it use `eth_sign` to sign message. From [here](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/signing-data.html#a-brief-history), I also checked [eth-sig-util](https://github.com/MetaMask/eth-sig-util) , I didn't find out the result.

How to use web3.js on server side to get the same result `a` ?

```html
<button onClick="signMessage()">Sign Message</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/web3/1.7.0-rc.0/web3.min.js" integrity="sha512-/PTXSvaFzmO4So7Ghyq+DEZOz0sNLU4v1DP4gMOfY3kFu9L/IKoqSHZ6lNl3ZoZ7wT20io3vu/U4IchGcGIhfw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script>
    async function signMessage() {
        if (!window.ethereum) return alert("Please Install Metamask");

        // connect to metamask

        //account is unlocked in local geth, it's the current user in Metamask
        let account="0x9ea35.......A0F0"

        console.log("pop up metamask")

        let master_private = '0x7f2dba38c0.........81e4e65a33866'

        let data = '0xc54c873f702196a21442bab405c89fd1a1f84a589fbe67398d33b0dd49057ac7'

        //Metamask instance in chrome, currently connect to http://127.0.0.1:8545
        let a = await new Web3(window.ethereum).eth.sign(data, account)
        // a = 0xfe5d26bdb4c295cecd75ae27021e3ae8101ab2ff4efa065b466a8100c1740b0c0d87f8a5cf0444d275663818e5a424c460c3d472dba34a3053f0b075c7bfe76a1c
     

        let w3=new Web3("http://127.0.0.1:8545")
        let b = await w3.eth.sign(data, account)
        // b = 0xb99e8f5253f570b6f2f67804301f45791047d8c4b24b7566b895c017e951da003a6a317a0713aa157598db8c4949284ca99ae0d628c5f4f1f17343a4abd520891c

        // b=c=d=e
        const c = await window.ethereum?.request({ method: 'personal_sign', params: [data, account], })

        let d = await w3.eth.personal.sign(data, account,"password") // geth enable --http.api --http.api "db,eth,net,web3,personal"

        let e = await w3.eth.accounts.sign(data, master_private)

        console.log('sign data:', data, 'got sig:', a, ', ', b, ', ', c, ', ', d, ', ', e.signature)

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the [`web3.eth.accounts.sign(data, privateKey);`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.3/web3-eth-accounts.html#sign) function can be found [here](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/blob/436e77a8eaa061fbaa183a9f73ca590c2e1d7697/packages/web3-eth-accounts/src/index.js#L434):

```
Accounts.prototype.sign = function sign(data, privateKey) {
    if (!privateKey.startsWith('0x')) {
        privateKey = '0x' + privateKey;
    }

    // 64 hex characters + hex-prefix
    if (privateKey.length !== 66) {
        throw new Error("Private key must be 32 bytes long");
    }

    var hash = this.hashMessage(data);
    var signature = Account.sign(hash, privateKey);
    var vrs = Account.decodeSignature(signature);
    return {
        message: data,
        messageHash: hash,
        v: vrs[0],
        r: vrs[1],
        s: vrs[2],
        signature: signature
    };
};
```

For a detailed explanation with propper examples, see [this](https://hukenneth.medium.com/ethereum-using-web3-js-for-message-signing-7e2935b2958c).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I included `web3.eth.accounts.sign` in my question. It's the `e`, but the result of `e` is different from `a`. The `web3.eth.accounts.sign` is not my expected.